# I want to clean up a list of names and email addresses using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to replace the email prefix with the full first name using sed - drop the . and the initial and replace with the first name from the beginning of the line.

```
Antony          Clark           a.clark@zzz123.co     ZZZ
Caroline        Foster          c.foster@zzz123.co    ZZZ
```

Eg. `a.clark@zzz123.co` will become `antony.clark@zzz123.co`

thanks!

Comment: Are those columns separated by tab chars of multiple spaces? Pleased edit your Q to answer this, rather that reply in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not glamorous, but `awk` with `printf` to preserve your formatting can be done as:

```
$  awk '{sub(/^[^.]+/,tolower($1),$3); printf "%-16s%-16s%-28s%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' emails
Antony          Clark           antony.clark@zzz123.co      ZZZ
Caroline        Foster          caroline.foster@zzz123.co   ZZZ
```

If you simply want single space separated output, then that reduces to:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[^.]+/,tolower($1),$3)}1' emails
Antony Clark antony.clark@zzz123.co ZZZ
Caroline Foster caroline.foster@zzz123.co ZZZ
```

(you can change the *output field-separator* to anything you desire)

Look things over and let me know if one of those will work.

Comment: They both work, thank you.  I was hoping to do this with sed but I awk deals with tabular data better fashion?  Thank for your help.

Comment: I also need to ignore the header ....

Comment: `awk` deal with *fields* better. What header do you need to ignore? I just see 2 names and emails with ZZZ at the end. What part needs to be ignored?

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hey one more thing has me stumped.  How do I tell awk to ignore the first line in the file?  There is a column header in the file that I don't want passed to awk.

Comment: Just use `awk 'NR==1 {next}` as a rule to skip the first line. The built-in `NR` (record number) corresponds to the record (line) number being processed, and `next` just say skip everything and go read the next record. If you have multiple-files as input to `awk` use `FNR==1` to skip the first line in each file (where `FNR` is the file-record-number).

Comment: I think I got it.  I added NR > 3 at the beginning of the awk statement to bypass the header info line.

Comment: That works too. Always more than one way to *skin-the-cat*.